# One validation function for multiple inputs

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I'm using CodeIgniter's form validation callback function, here is it:

```
function _validate_rate($input, $field)
{

    if ( !in_array($field, array("water", "earth", "fire")) )
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $min = (int) $this->input->post($field . '_max');
    if ( $min > 0 AND $min < $input )
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message($field . '_min', sprintf($this->lang->line('dev_s_invalid_rate'), strtolower($field)));
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

.. I'm using the above function for three form inputs:

```
$form_rules = array(
    'water_min' => array (
        'field' => substr($this->lang->line('dev_field_water'), 0, -1), 
        'rules' => 'trim|xss_clean|max_length[4]|numeric|callback__validate_rate[water]'
    ),
    'earth_min' => array (
        'field' => substr($this->lang->line('dev_field_earth'), 0, -1), 
        'rules' => 'trim|xss_clean|max_length[4]|numeric|callback__validate_rate[earth]'
    ),
    'fire_min' => array (
        'field' => substr($this->lang->line('dev_field_fire'), 0, -1), 
        'rules' => 'trim|xss_clean|max_length[4]|numeric|callback__validate_rate[fire]'
    )
);
foreach( $form_rules as $input => $data) 
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($input, $data['field'], $data['rules']);
}
```

The problem appears, when I want to display a form validation error message with the following statement:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message($field . '_min', sprintf($this->lang->line('dev_s_invalid_rate'), strtolower($field)));
```

(in the callback function).

So: it should set a error message corresponding to the `$field` data, so when the `$field` is `water`, it should set a error message  for `water_min` (as that is the validation rule field name).. but then I'm receiving following message:

`Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name.`.

I've created one callback function for three fields, just to prevent repeating same looking functions, which will have to check/work the same... unfortunately the errors corresponding to the each input can not be accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$this->form_validation->set_message($field . '_min', sprintf($this->lang->line('dev_s_invalid_rate'), strtolower($field)));
```

to

```
$this->form_validation->set_message(_validate_rate, sprintf($this->lang->line('dev_s_invalid_rate'), strtolower($field)));
```

The error message corresponds to the function, not the field. That way your function can be generically used for multiple fields. In your error message you could write:

```
'The %s field is not correct'
```

and it will insert the field name into the %s